# Query DynamoDB between certain dates -NodeJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to query Dynamo DB for person_id between two dates. I have errors with the following code:

Please note that the primary key of the table is (event_id), but I'm not sure how/where to use it?

```js
 

var params = {
        TableName: "tableName",
        IndexName: "person_id-event_date-index",
        FilterExpression: "#person_id =:person_id",
        KeyConditionExpression: "#person_id = :person_id and #event_date BETWEEN :from AND :to",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#person_id": "person_id",
            "#event_date": "event_date"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":person_id": person_id,
            ":from": start_date,
            ":to": end_date
        }
    }
documentClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        callback(new Error(JSON.stringify(err)))
    }
    else {
        callback(null, data);
    }
});
```

Can anyone please check how to make this working?

Many thanks

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing from this query?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you cannot do that unless the Table has some [GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) (Global Secondary Indexes) set up that allow for that sort of query.

When doing a query you **must** pass a primary key value, you cannot do a query otherwise.

Considering that you want to query based on a different column, not the primary key, you need to see if you have an index defined with

- PrimaryKey = person_id and
- RangeKey = event_date

If such an index is note defined you may rely on [scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html), but that's not recommended.

Comment: I have GSI for the person_id and event_date, and its already included it in the code above. I even tried scan instead of query. I'm getting the same error for both query and scan: error: 'Value provided in ExpressionAttributeNames unused in expressions: keys: {#event_date}'

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix code:

```js
  

   var params = {
                TableName: "tableName" ,
                IndexName: "person_id-event_date-index",
                KeyConditionExpression: "#person_id = :person_id and #event_date BETWEEN :from AND :to",
                ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                    "#person_id": "person_id",
                    "#event_date": "event_date"
                },
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ":person_id": person_id,
                    ":from": start_date,
                    ":to": end_date
                }
        }

    documentClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            callback(new Error(JSON.stringify(err)))
        }
        else {
callback(null, data);
        }
    });
  }
```